# Hackerrank Lattice Paths in Javascript

Tags: javascript, north-east-lattice-path

I am working on the [project euler lattice](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15) path problem in Javascript.
I used the recursive method and solved it in project euler. Below is my function,

```
const latticePathsRecursive = (m, n = m) => {
    if (m < 0 || n < 0) return 0;
    if (m === 0 && n === 0) return 1;
    return (latticePathsRecursive(m - 1, n) + latticePathsRecursive(m, n - 1));
}
```

I tried the same in Hackerrank(test cases have both square & rectangular grid) but all the hidden test cases `timed out` and failed.

So I tried using Combinatorial Solution and except for the sample test case and one hidden test case all the other test cases failed - `wrong answer`.

I can't figure out where it went wrong. But why 3 test cases pass and the rest throws `wrong answer`? Am I missing something while using the formula here?

```
const latticePathsCombinatorial = (a, b) => {
   const factorial = (number) => {
      if (number === 1 || number === 0) {
         return 1;
      } else {
         return number * factorial(number - 1);
      }
   }

   let n = a + b,
   k = a;

   // 'n choose k' = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)
   return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am fairly certain that your code is failing because there is a constraint you have not noticed on Hackerrank: "As number of ways can be very large, print it modulo (10^9 + 7)."

Comment: @vera. Actually, while printing I added modulo (10^9+7). `console.log(latticePathsCombinatorial(n, m) % 1000000007)`.

Comment: Yeah but the number is too big to be accurately represented. It's already incorrect before you use modulo.

Comment: Maybe BigInt will work I guess. Let me try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, when I converted all the numbers to `BigInt`.
Since some answers are too big, handling everything in `BigInt` solved the problem.

```
let M = 1000000007n;
        
let n = BigInt(a) + BigInt(b),
    k = BigInt(a);
let res = (factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))) % M;
return Number(res);
```